# How to remove cache from my Block class?

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, cache, full-page-cache

I need to remove the cache from my Block class, even if it removes the cache from the entire page.

How could I do it?

Comment: You've already tried to add ```cacheable=false``` in your layout xml? More info here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html
Example: https://meetanshi.com/blog/disable-cache-for-block-using-xml-in-magento-2/

Comment: Yes @MattiaKozianowski, but in this case, I can't control it via admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `HTTP` class and call the method `setNoCacheHeaders`, as you can see below.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http;

public function myCustomMethod(){
    $this->response->setNoCacheHeaders();
    ...
}
```

It will implement this module below, which will set no-cache in the header.

[image: Magento 2 remove cache from Block class]

Comment: where should I call this method in block or in phtml file?

Comment: In your Block class, inside the method that you are using.

Comment: can you please add the code here?

Comment: Hi @MohitRane, the code is above the image.

Comment: yes, I know. But I can't see the code after `max-age` Is there any further code?

Comment: I just put the image to show inside the method, instead of set the headers again, you just need to add the setNoCacheHeaders() in your code.

Comment: okay, got it. Thank you for your response.